# Change message depending on time of day?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change a message depending on the time of day.

I've pasted what I'm looking at in ST2 into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/EVCMm/)

Here it is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="time">
        <p id="time">Good morning.</p>
    </div>

<div>
    <p>I used to work in the marketing industry.<br>Now I'm a Web Designer and Developer.<br> I like to keep things simple.</p>
</div>​
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
      var now = new Date();
      var hours = now.getHours();
      var msg;
      if(hours<12)
           msg = "Good Morning";
      else if(hours<18)
           msg = "Good Afternoon";
      else
          msg = "Good Evening";
      return(msg);
    });
});
</script>​
```

I'm a complete noob when it comes to jquery so be gentle.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var now = new Date();
      var hours = now.getHours();
      var msg;
      if (hours < 12) msg = "Good Morning";
      else if (hours < 18) msg = "Good Afternoon";
      else msg = "Good Evening";
      $('#time p').text(msg);
    });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="time">
        <p>Good morning.</p>
    </div>

<div>
    <p>I used to work in the marketing industry.<br>Now I'm a Web Designer and Developer.<br> I like to keep things simple.</p>
</div>​
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: you need to tell it where to put the msg.  Target the p tag, either by providing an id, name etc then set the text of that tag as the msg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `return msg` to `$('#time p').text(msg);`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/EVCMm/10/

This uses jQuery `text()` method to replace the text looking for the `p` tag within `ID=time`

API reference:  http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: That works on JSFiddle – just not when viewing on localhost. Any reason why (updated original q with html)

Comment: look in your browser debug console to see if errors thrown. Likely a syntax problem somewhere

Answer (score -4):

```
$('#time').html('<p>'+msg+'</p>');
```

Comment: for someone with so much reputation, that is a really terrible answer.  At least explain the answer don't just provide code.  Tell the OP why his code doesn't work and explain what your code is doing.

Comment: Feel free to adjust my reputation.

Comment: I would if I could, so would many others.  I stand by what I said, your answer does nothing to help the OP become a better programmer, nor to understand why it is his code does not work.  Copy and pasting code you do not understand will never help anyone.

Comment: @JonTaylor, adjusting my reputation takes a downvote, you can do that. Other than that your judgement is an insult to the OP, I assume he is not a braindead copypaster and can do some research of his own.

Comment: I have down voted.  I have never assumed the OP is a braindead copy paster, however, I would expect anyone who helps others to actually try and teach them rather than just tell them the answer.

Comment: @JonTaylor, saying "Copy and pasting code you do not understand will never help anyone" and claiming your have never assumed the OP is a braindead copy paster makes your comments highly irrelevant, so there's no point in discussing it any further.